# Parsing a C++ source file after preprocessing

Tags: c++, c, parsing

I am trying to analyze `c++` files using my custom made parser (written in `c++`). Before start parsing, I will like to get rid of all `#define`.  I want the source file to be compilable after preprocessing. So best way will be to run `C Preprocessor` on the file.

```
cpp myfile.cpp temp.cpp
// or
g++ -E myfile.cpp > templ.cpp
```

[New suggestions are welcome.]

But due to this, the original lines and their line numbers will be lost as the file will contain all the header information also and I want to retain the line numbers. So the way out I have decided is,

1. Add a special symbol before
   every line in the source file (except preprocessors)
2. Run the preprocessor
3. Extract the lines with that special
   symbol and analyze them

For example, a typical source file will look like:

```
#include<iostream>
#include"xyz.h"
int x;    
#define SOME value
/*
**  This is a test file
*/
typedef char* cp;

void myFunc (int* i, ABC<int, X<double> > o)
{
  //...
}

class B {
};
```

After adding symbol it will be like,

```
#include<iostream>
#include"xyz.h"
@3@int x;    
#define SOME value
@5@/*
@6@**  This is a test file
@7@*/
@8@typedef char* cp;
@9@
@10@void myFunc (int* i, ABC<int, X<double> > o)
@11@{
@12@  //...
@13@}
@14@
@15@class B {
@16@};
```

Once all the macros and comments are removed, I will be left with thousands of line in which few hundred will be the original source code.

**Is this approach correct ? Am I missing any corner case ?**

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Michael, I want to get rid of MACROs (i.e. `#define`) from the source files, before I start analyzing them with my parser.

Comment: I too don't know what your ultimate goal is. For academic purposes, you might want to have a look at the Clang front end (http://clang.llvm.org/), it has a modular design and it's something you can integrate in other applications/tools.

Comment: @Julio, Not for academic purpose. Once the parsing is done, I will be **modifying the source** code in certain way. However, explaining all will be too much to write. I hope at least my question is explanatory. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: @iammilind: Unless this is for academic purposes, I think attempting to write your own C++ frontend is kind of insane. A ton of things like template instantiation and argument dependent lookup can be extremely complicated to implement correctly, and there are at least two excellent and freely available C++ front ends available that you can use (`g++` and LLVM's `clang`), each of which have **millions** of development hours, and **still** often contain serious bugs.

Comment: @Billy, you are correct. However, I have been writing this parser for last 2 years and have reached at considerably good stage. Only major part remaining is the preprocessing; which I don't want to waste time on. My intention was to simply replace pointers and new/delete with my custom symbols; which I am able to do.

Comment: @iammilind: 2 years < millions of development hours. I'm not saying it's impossible to build, but it's *insanely* hard. Good luck! (Your question asks if it makes sense to take such an approach, and my answer is that that approach is off the rocker. However, I'm saying that about parsing rather than preprocessing, which is not directly what the question asks for, which is why it's a comment rather than an answer)

Comment: @Billy, I never meant my efforts are more. sorry if you felt so. The thing is that, I am not writing a compiler but a source code modifier. For example, if it's declared as `int *p;`, I would replace it as `Wrap<int> i;` (just an example); or if it's `p = new int;`, I would make it `p = myAlloc<int>()` and so on. From overview of Clang, I don't know whether it provides such facility.

Comment: Clang does provide some facility for building and modifying ASTs.  Being able to do this right is pretty hard and I agree with Billy that attempting to do this yourself is going to (continue to be) very difficult.  If you think you have the problem pretty well solved after two years, Ok, then great; if not, you really should look at other working solutions.  The fact that you are having troubles with line numbers suggests you are nowhere near a working solution that handles the harder issues.  For instance, where is the symbol X actually defined? This is more work than the parser.

Comment: ... If you have not yet looked at other solutions, you should consider: Clang, Rose, OpenC++, Elsa, Oink and our tool, DMS. All of these parse C++ (several with ability to expand preprocessor directives while capturing accurate file/line/column information [including DMS]) and provide ability to build ASTs, transform them, and regenerate source code.  Only some can resolve symbol names [for me, that's a crucial capability for serious transformation capability]: Clang, Rose, DMS, and I don't know about Elsa and Oink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You realize that g++ -E adds some of its own lines to its output which indicate line numbers in the original file? You'll find lines like

```
# 2 "foo.cc" 2
```

which indicate that you're looking at line 2 of file foo.cc . These lines are inserted whenever the regular sequence of lines is disrupted.

Comment: Those lines are added only for headers, I guess. For general code it isn't.

Comment: @iammilind: no, they're added after every file change. you can deduce the actual line numbers from it.

Comment: @Mat, But can I extract the original file source code ? If I have preprocessed "x.cpp" then I am interested only in analyzing "x.cpp" source. Generally they are cluttered with lot of other `namespaces` and `function declarations`, which I am not interested in.

Comment: @iammilind: after each `# n "foo.cpp" x` you know the following lines (until the next `# q "file.x" y`) are from foo.cpp line n and following. so yes, you know exactly where you are all the time.

Comment: @Mat, you are correct. That will save lot of work for me. The only thing is I have to keep tracking for `"foo.cpp"` with numbers `n` and `x`. Mostly this appears in the beginning and end of the preprocessed file. Never noticed it properly.

Answer (score 1):

The `imake` program that used to come with X11 sources used a faintly similar system, marking the ends of lines with `@@` so that it could post-process them properly.

The output from `gcc -E` usually includes `#line` directives; you could perhaps use those instead of your symbols.

Comment: Interesting. But I will not like to use `#` as it is used else where also. Is the current approach mentioned in question correct ?

Comment: @iammilind: the output from GCC will include the `#line` directives, probably in the abbreviated form without the keyword `line` as mentioned by Ernest.  You can use `@99@` to mark the start of lines. I quoted a historical precedent for using `@@`; admittedly, that was at the end of the line rather than at the start, but the `@` symbol is one of the better choices (visible and not otherwise used by C).