# Determine Cobol coding style

Tags: parsing, cobol

I'm developing an application that parses Cobol programs. In these programs some respect the traditional coding style (programm text from column 8 to 72), and some are newer and don't follow this style.

In my application I need to determine the coding style in order to know if I should parse content after column 72.

I've been able to determine if the program start at column 1 or 8, but prog that start at column 1 can also follow the rule of comments after column 72.

So I'm trying to find rules that will allow me to determine if texts after column 72 are comments or valid code.

I've find some but it's hard to tell if it will work everytime :

- dot after column 72, determine the end of sentence but I fear that dot can be in comments too
- find the close character of a statement after column 72 : `" ' ) }`
- look for char at columns 71 - 72 - 73, if there is not space then find the whole word, and check if it's a key word or a var. Problem, it can be a var from a COPY or a replacement etc...

**I'd like to know what do you think of these rules and if you have any ideas to help me determine the coding style of a Cobol program.**

*I don't need an API or something just solid rules that I will be able to rely on.*

Comment: @JerryCoffin Are you saying that because not any Cobol prog look the same :) ? I've to parse Cobol and all the different formattings are really a pain... By the way if you have any ideas they are welcome thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no absolutely reliable way to determine if a COBOL program
is in fixed or free format based only on the source code. Heck it is sometimes difficult to identify
the programming language based only on source code. Check out 
this classic [polyglot](http://ideology.com.au/polyglot/polyglot.txt) - it is valid under 8 different language compilers. That 
said, you could try a few heuristics that might yield 
the correct answer more often than not.

**Compiler directives imbedded in source code**

Watch for certain compiler directives that determine code format.
Unfortunately, every compiler vendor uses their own flavour of directive.

For example, Microfocus COBOL uses the
`SOURCEFORMAT` directive. This directive will appear near the top of the program so a short pre-scan
could be used to find it. On the other hand, OpenCobol uses `>>SOURCE FORMAT IS FREE` and
`>>SOURCE FORMAT IS FIXED` to toggle between free and fixed format, different parts of the same program
could be formatted differently!

The bottom line here is that you will have to support the conventions of multiple COBOL compilers.

**Compiler switches**

Source code format can be also be specified using a compiler switch. In this case, there are no concrete
clues to go on. However, you can be reasonably sure that the entire source program will be either
fixed or free. All you can do here is guess. Unless the programmer is out to "mess with
your head" (and some will), a program in free format will have the keywords `IDENTIFICATION DIVISION` or `ID DIVISION`, starting before column 8.
Every COBOL program will begin with these keywords so you can use them as the anchor point for determining code format in the
absence of imbedded compiler directives.

Warning - this is far from fool proof, but might be a good start.

Comment: @alain.janinm the `IDENTIFICATION` or `ID` keywords may be preceeded by other compiler directives or comments, but these are the first actual COBOL keywords that *every* valid COBOL program will begin with. If they begin before column 8 the source format is most likely free, between column 8 and 12 it is most likely fixed format.

Comment: Thanks a lot for hints, I will make further research to know if I can add that to the parser ;) With the 3 heuristics above , an other one and adapted weightings I've already been able to determine the correct style of code for most of the programms, with your clues I will probably be able to do it faster and more accurate in some cases.

Comment: I know about DIVISION, I already worked on that but it can't tell me if the right limit is 72 (I have programms starting at column 8 and not respecting the right limit). The fact about compiler directive is more interesting ;)

Comment: The polyglot example is quite funny :D I never seen something like that! Fortunately my progs are not so complicated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to know the COBOL compiler for each program.  Its documentation should tell you what conventions/configurations/switches it uses to decide if the source code ends at column 72 or not.

So.... which compiler(s)?

And if you think the column 72 issue is a pain, wait till you get around to actually parsing the COBOL itself.   If you are not well prepared to handle the lexical issues of the language, you are probably very badly prepared to handle the syntactic ones.

Comment: The fact is all programms don't use the same compiler that's the problem. And I already done Cobol parsing and I need this to be actually able to parse correctly the lexical and semantic level. From now I change a variable to fix column limit depending on the Cobol project but now I'd like to be able to determine it and not to have to enter it myself.

Comment: Why don't you associate "the compiler" with each file; then you'd know what conventions to apply?

Comment: Yes it can be a solution but I've not an access to compiler options for each programm, that the problem :) ! For some of them I have to open it read it and guess what are the options used... I'd like to limit the human action and only use a parser to resolve my problem.

Comment: OK, then you're stuck.  If you want a reliable solution, just try parsing the files both ways.   If you're not sure which compiler, you're going to need a full parser for *each* compiler dialect.   You obviously have at least 2.   COBOLs vary more than one would expect; that might be a lot of work.

Comment: "that *might* be a lot of work". Just got my vote for understatement of the year!

Comment: @NealB: You haven't see the SO question for guy building his own C++ parser. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5864858/120163

Comment: @IraBaxter With heuristics and weightings I've managed the coding style detection for most of the programms. I think I will determine a range of probabilities that are not enough meaningful and for those one I will end "parsing the files both ways". I've already both parsers (it's the goal of the project find coding style is more a "bonus" :) ) so it's more a problem of performance, I prefer avoid to parse twice the same programm! Thanks for advices!

Answer (score 1):

There won't be an algorithm to do this with 100% certainty, because if comments can be anything, they can also be compilable COBOL code. So you could theoretically write a program that means one thing if the comments are ignored, and something else entirely if the comments are treated as part of the COBOL.

But that's extremely unlikely. What's most likely to happen is that if you try to compile the code under the wrong convention, it will simply fail. So the only accurate way to do this is to try compiling/parsing the program one way, and if you come to a line that can't make sense, switch to the other style. You could also support passing an argument to the compiler when the style is already known.

You can try using heuristics like what you've described, but that will never be totally accurate. The most they can give you is a *probability* that the code is one or the other style, which will increase as they examine more and more lines of code. They could be useful for helping you guess the style before you start compiling, or for figuring out when the problem is really just a typo in the code.

#### EDIT:

Regarding ideas for heuristics, it's hard to say. If there were a standard comment sigil like `//` or `#` in other languages, this would be a lot easier ([actually, there is](http://www.gavilan.edu/csis/languages/comments.html#_Toc53710123), but it sounds like your code doesn't follow this convention). The only thing I can think of would be to check whether every line (or maybe 99% of lines, and not counting empty lines or lines commented with `*`) has a period somewhere before position 72.

One thing you DON'T want to do is apply any heuristics to the part *after* position 72. That is, you don't want to be checking the comments to see if they're valid COBOL. You want to check what you *know* is COBOL first, and see if that works by itself. There are several reasons for this:

- Comments written in English are likely to have periods and quotes in them, so your first and second bullet points are out.
- Natural languages are WAY harder to parse than something like COBOL.
- The comments could easily have COBOL in them (maybe someone commented out the previous version of the line).
- An important rule for comments is that they should never affect what the program does. If changing the comments can change how the program is compiled, you violate that.

All that in mind, my opinion is that you shouldn't use heuristics at all. You should always try to compile the program under both conventions unless one is explicitly specified. There's a chance that code will compile successfully under both conventions, and then you'll have two different programs and no way to tell which one is correct.

If that happens, you need to compare the two results (perhaps with a hash or something) to see if they're the same program. If they're the same, great, but if not, you'll need to force the user to explicitly choose a convention.

Comment: That's the solution I've imaged too. I guess I will have to end with that. Have you got some more "heuristics" to suggest maybe? Thanks for having answering!

Comment: @alain.janinm - Maybe. I have one idea, and several cautions. See my edit.

Comment: Ok, so actually I already use the rules of comments but it help me to know the "left alignment" but not the right one. And finally I've use the heuristics above (with some more conditions of course - as you said exceptions are possible) and it give pretty good results! PS: just for clarify I'm not modifying the code or trying to compile or execute it, I just parse it to be able to make a map of progs, and to analyse semantic errors or things that are likely to cause odd behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Most COBOL compilers will allow you to generate and analyze the post text manipulation phase.

The text preprocessor output can be seen (using OpenCOBOL for the example)

```
cobc -E program.cob
```

The text manipulation processor deals with any COPY ... REPLACING compiler directives, as well as converting SOURCE FORMAT IS FIXED (with line continuations, string literal concatenations, comment line removal, among other things) to the actual free format that the compiler lexical analyzer needs.  A lot of the OpenCOBOL toolkits (Cross referencer and Animator, to name two) use source code AFTER the preprocessor pass.  I don't think you'll lose any street cred if your parser program relies on post processed source code files.